# Asp.net UrlWriting

Tags: asp.net

can any one tell me why url rewriting not working in iis6?

Comment: Yes! You've configured it wrong! (You'll need to provide more details, or perhaps I can guess: You need to Uncheck 'Verify file exists' in your wildcard mapping).

Comment: @Noon Silk - dude, u sure IIS6 has a rewriter built in?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: It doesn't, but you can still do it yourself - It's how I've done it for ages (custom HttpModule or just something in the Global.asax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can - IIS6 doesn't have any built in URL ReWriter. IIS7 does - but it's an [add-on that needs to be downloaded separately](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).

Of course, there are 3rd party Url Rewriter's which I think exist for IIS6, but it's been *ages* since I've used IIS6.

Pro Tip #1: Migrate over to IIS7.

Pro Tip #2: This question should be asked on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) instead.

Comment: No Probs :) If u're ahppy with the answer, then don't forget to tick it.